# Wazuh agent when ran from AWS [Ec2] userdata doesn't work correctly

Tags: amazon-ec2, wazuh, ec2-userdata

Wazuh agent fim module is not working when wazuh-agent service is started in the user data script. The service starts and there's nothing wierd in ossec logs but nothing shows up in the dashboard. Fim starts working after I ssh into the instance and do a systemctl restart wazuh-agent. My user data script looks like this (variable assignments was omitted) :

`yum update -y; WAZUH_MANAGER="${WAZUH_WORKER}" WAZUH_REGISTRATION_SERVER="${WAZUH_AUTH}" WAZUH_AGENT_NAME="${AGENT_NAME}" WAZUH_AGENT_GROUP="default" WAZUH_REGISTRATION_PASSWORD="${AUTH_PASSWORD}" yum install -y https://packages.wazuh.com/4.x/yum/wazuh-agent-4.3.9-1.x86_64.rpm; systemctl daemon-reload; systemctl enable wazuh-agent; systemctl start wazuh-agent;`

I'm using centralized agent configuration. Not sure if the agent.conf is not getting pulled in user-data since it eventually does get pulled when I ssh into the instance.

The expected result was wazuh agent working normally and sending fim changes to dashboard once they happen. What i got was the fim module did nothing untill wazuh agent service was restart after sshing into the instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some testing based on your script, I found the following:

- FIM is working ok, the inventory of files being monitored in my case for a t2.micro Amazon Linux 2 machine is taking about 9 minutes to be built from the moment the EC2 was launched
- The `agent.conf` file is being imported to the recently launched endpoint, without SSHing in to the host I confirmed this by checking the configuration of this Agent for integrity monitoring in the Wazuh Web UI, where I added `<directories check_all="yes" whodata="yes">/root</directories>` to the default configuration that can be found here: [Default syscheck configuration](https://documentation.wazuh.com/current/user-manual/reference/ossec-conf/syscheck.html#default-syscheck-configuration)

**First script I used:**

```
#!/bin/bash
yum update -y; WAZUH_MANAGER='172.30.0.5' WAZUH_REGISTRATION_PASSWORD='please123' WAZUH_AGENT_GROUP='linuxtest' yum install -y https://packages.wazuh.com/4.x/yum/wazuh-agent-4.3.8-1.x86_64.rpm; systemctl daemon-reload; systemctl enable wazuh-agent; systemctl start wazuh-agent; touch /root/carlostest
```

I assumed that it can detect changes after building the inventory of files being monitored, therefore I added a `sleep 600` to test this and it was successful, I got a "File added to the system" rule.id 554

**Second script I used:**

```
#!/bin/bash
yum update -y; WAZUH_MANAGER='172.30.0.5' WAZUH_REGISTRATION_PASSWORD='please123' WAZUH_AGENT_GROUP='linuxtest' yum install -y https://packages.wazuh.com/4.x/yum/wazuh-agent-4.3.8-1.x86_64.rpm; systemctl daemon-reload; systemctl enable wazuh-agent; systemctl start wazuh-agent; sleep 600; touch /root/carlostest
```

Note: I am using Wazuh 4.3.8 since I already had a testing environment with this version, I noticed you are using 4.3.9 but I do not think much changed with that minor update, still you can test with a different version by changing the link and see what happens

I hope this information is helpful to you, let me know

**Edit:** Bear in mind the default configuration do not alert for changes on real time, that is why I added `whodata` to the directory I was testing on. Probably you just detect the changes when the wazuh-agent is restarted because that is part of the default configuration on `<scan_on_start>yes</scan_on_start>`. I recommend you to check the following documentation:

- [File Integrity Monitoring - Wazuh](https://documentation.wazuh.com/current/user-manual/capabilities/file-integrity/index.html)
- [syscheck](https://documentation.wazuh.com/current/user-manual/reference/ossec-conf/syscheck.html#default-syscheck-configuration)

Comment: Found out the reason that caused the problem for me. Docker was creating the directory I was mounting and tracking so inotify couldn't track the changes when the wazuh-agent service was started. By the time i sshed into the instance, the directory was created by docker and restarting the agent also restarted inotify to track the now created directory. I just had to create the directory before starting the agent. Anyway the answer above proved helpful in diagnosing.